# GCM using smack library NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout

Tags: smack, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to gcm and I tried to connect to Cloud Connection Server(XMPP) of GCM using Smack API. It was alright at the start,
My code:

```
uid = "123456789";
apiKey = "A**************B";
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config;
config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
    config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    config.setUsernameAndPassword(uid,apiKey);
    config.setServiceName("gcm.googleapis.com");
    config.setHost("gcm.googleapis.com");
    config.setPort(5235);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    mConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
    try {
         mConnection.connect();
         mConnection.login();
        }
   catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception at SmackCcsClient.init()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I couldnt get past the initial handshaking process. I used some dummy random GCMIDs to test downstream messaging at first and it was showing up in the smack debug window but later on, the same code shows nothing after the following xml feed as **Raw sent packets**:

```
<stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='gcm.googleapis.com'  xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
```

and i tried

```
mConnection.login(uid+"@gcm.googleapis.com",apiKey);//even though i assume its next step of the handshake.
```

Console prints the following errors:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 10000ms (~10s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:85)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:253)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:146)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWaitOrThrow(SynchronizationPoint.java:125)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:837)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:360)
at psdc.gcm.SmackCcsClient.init(SmackCcsClient.java:64)
at psdc.gcm.GCMServer.activate(GCMServer.java:44)
at psdc.servlets.Mapper.selectIds(Mapper.java:191)
at psdc.servlets.Mapper.doPost(Mapper.java:152)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 25, 2015 5:36:18 PM org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:2965)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3003)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1409)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1394)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1092)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1151)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to solve this as i am really stuck with this and nowhere to go.Please tell me a way to check if my xml request reaches google or not.

Am using the SMACK library version 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible); solved my problem. It defines the configuration of the connection to be used.It Turns on TLS if the server supports the same.

refer : http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration.html

```
config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible);
        config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
        config.setUsernameAndPassword(uid,apiKey);
        config.setServiceName("gcm.googleapis.com");
        config.setHost("gcm.googleapis.com");
        config.setPort(5235);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
            mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
            mConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000);

            try {
                mConnection.connect();
```

Hope it helps someone.