# FCM/GCM App Server cannot connect to FCM/GCM CCS using SSLSocket and SMACK library

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, smack

I'm writing a Firebase Cloud Messaing (FCM) App server program, and encountered a connection problem when I try to connect to FCM server via XMPP connection, using SMACK library. The program fails to be connected to the FCM server (fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5236).

Following an example,
https://github.com/carlosCharz/fcmxmppserverv2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wedevol/xmpp/server/CcsClient.java,

I try to connect to the FCM server using SSL socket. The source codes are as follows.

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder ();
configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword (senderId, serverKey);
configBuilder.setServiceName (CCMServiceName);
configBuilder.setHost (CCMServer);
configBuilder.setPort (CCMServerPort);
configBuilder.setSocketFactory (SSLSocketFactory.getDefault ());
configBuilder.setSecurityMode (SecurityMode.ifpossible);
configBuilder.setSendPresence (true);
configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");


//Step 2. Generate a connection resource with CCM Server
connection = new XMPPTCPConnection (configBuilder.build ());

//Step 3. Connect
try {
  systemLogStream.println ("Try to connect XMPP end-point: " + CCMServer );
  connection.connect();
} catch (SmackException smackEx) {
  systemLogStream.println ("SMACK Exception: " + smackEx.getMessage());
  System.exit(999);
} catch (XMPPException xmppEx) {
  systemLogStream.println ("XMPP Exception: ");
} catch (IOException ioEx) {
  systemLogStream.println ("IO Exception: ");
}
```

However, it always fails to connect to FCM server generating following exception.

```
SMACK Exception: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
```

To figure out the reason, I captured tcpdumps and it looks like SSLSocket does not send Clienthello message which is the first step to TLS handshake. Following is the result from Wireshark.

[Wireshark capture result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zucp7.png)

I hope that someone nice gives a comment or an advise how to resolve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31268247/5832311). Try using [`configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible);`](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration.html) instead. This defines the configuration of the connection to be used. It Turns on TLS if the server supports the same. You may also check this [related thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/5mA7FImpTGo) if it helps.

Comment: We resolved the probem. It was the firewall problem: FCM server uses many different IP addresses for the same URL (fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com). Thus, the traffic has been morphed if the TCP traffic goes to an IP not registered in my firewall. Anyway, thank you for the comment!